# Function is not returning value: scope issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

Need a second pair of eyes... spot anything wrong with this? My inner function is not returning the value. I must be messing something up with the scope?

```
 function getGroups(account){
    var name;
   // name = 'assigned'; I work
    account.getGroups(function(err, groups) {
        //removed logic for simple debugging 
        name ='test';
        //return name;
    });
    return name;
}
```

When assigning the variable in the parent function ie `var name = 'assigned'` it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `account.getGroups` might be an asynchronous function and it takes a `callback` function. this `callback` function,

```
function(err, groups) {
        //removed logic for simple debugging 
        name ='test';
        //return name;
    }
```

does not get executed instantaneously. So your `return name;` statements gets executed before your `name = 'test';` statement.

Hope it makes sense.

---

to get the updated value from the callback you have to make the `getGroups` asynchronous or event based

making asynchronous is easy

```
function getGroups(account, callback){
    var name;
   // name = 'assigned'; I work
    account.getGroups(function(err, groups) {
        //removed logic for simple debugging 
        name ='test';
        callback(name);
    });

}
```

and instead of calling the function for value (e.g., 'var groupname = getGroups(account)') you have to do like the following

```
getGroup(account, function (groupname){
   // do whatever you like with the groupname here inside this function
})
```

Comment: It does. However how can I structure this to maintain good non blocking code with the needed returned results? Would I pass a callback within my `getGroups`? `getGroups(account, callback)`

Comment: have given the detail

Answer (score 1):

Since `account.getGroups` is an async function, your own `getGroups` is also forced to be async. Instead of returning the name with a `return` statement, try passing the name to a callback once you have it:

```
function getGroups(account, onDone){
    account.getGroups(function(err, groups) {
        var name ='test';
        //...
        onDone(name);
    });
}
```

Code written with callbacks instead of return statements is said to be written in *continuation passing style*. You can google for that if you want more examples.

You might also want to pass a seconf "error" parameter to the callback to mimic the Nodejs interface if you want to propagate errors.